# Definite integral giving negative value as a result?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I want to calculate definite integral

$$\int_{-2}^{-1} \frac{1}{x^2}e^{\frac{1}{x}} dx = \Omega$$

$$\int \frac{1}{x^2}e^{\frac{1}{x}} dx=-e^{\frac{1}{x}}+C$$

so:

$$\Omega = [-e^{\frac{1}{-2}}]-[-e^{\frac{1}{-1}}]=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}} + \frac{1}{e}$$

which is a negative value. I believe it should be positive.

What went wrong in the process?

Comment: How exactly did you go about calculating the antiderivative? [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+(1%2Fx%5E2)+exp(1%2Fx%5E2)) gives a much different result.

Comment: Your antiderivative is completely incorrect: The derivative of $e^{1/x^2}$ is $e^{1/x^2} / (-x^3)$. The red flag that you found is indeed a correct one, and shows that your answer cannot be right. This is a good thing to check.

Comment: Thanks. I have fixed it now. I meant $\int \frac{1}{x^2} e^{\frac{1}{x}}dx$.

Comment: You flipped the interval's endpoints. $-2<-1$

Comment: And just to confirm, taking account of @mr_e_man’s comment above, your work seems correct.

Comment: Gosh. Can't accept your answer, because it's a comment. Thank you all.

Comment: I was actually "debugging" this integral for about an hour and missed that one... :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you effectively did was swap the order of evaluation for the fundamental theorem of calculus. Recall:

$$\int_a^b f(x)dx = F(b) - F(a)$$

when the antiderivative of $f$ is $F$. You instead have $F(a) - F(b)$ ($a=-2,b=-1$) in this case. The end result is merely a sign error - you have precisely the negative of the answer which you should expect.